# how to verify the port mesos is listening on

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

After I start memos-master on Ubuntu 14.04,  I'm unable to get to http://:5050
therefore I want to verify if Mesos is listening on the default port 5050.

I'm following the instructions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-production-ready-mesosphere-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04).

```
vagrant@master2:~$ sudo start mesos-master
mesos-master start/running, process 5272

vagrant@master1:~$ mesos help
Usage: mesos <command> [OPTIONS]

Available commands:
    help
    start-agents.sh
    daemon.sh
    stop-masters.sh
    start-masters.sh
    start-slaves.sh
    start-cluster.sh
    master
    stop-slaves.sh
    agent
    stop-cluster.sh
    stop-agents.sh
    log
    execute
    scp
    tail
    resolve
    ps
    init-wrapper
    local
    cat
```

I tried this to verify, but no result.

```
vagrant@master1:~$ sudo netstat -tnlp | grep 5050
```

I know Mesos is running but I get connection refused.

```
vagrant@master1:~$ curl http://192.168.2.1:5050
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.2.1 port 5050: Connection refused
```

Comment: Can you share the logs?

Answer (score -1):

I see you are using Vagrant so go the the browser in the host machine and type `<master2_ip>:5050`
`<master2_ip>` - replace it with the IP address of the `master2` using `ipaddr` or `ifconfig` to find the ip.

If the mesos is up and running you will get the mesos dashboard or else port unreachable error.

Post your `vagrantFile` here.